# Adding line height to formatted text in Swift

Tags: swift, formatting, nsattributedstring

I have text that uses the Atributika library to replace html tags with styled fonts. However I can't seem to add line height to this block of text:

```
        let emStyle = Style("em").font(.aicTextItalicFont)
        let iStyle = Style("i").font(.aicTextItalicFont)
        let strongStyle = Style("strong").font(.aicTextBoldFont)
        let bStyle = Style("b").font(.aicTextBoldFont)
        let allStyle = Style.font(.aicTextFont).baselineOffset(22.0 - Float(UIFont.aicTitleFont.pointSize))

        let eventDescription = eventModel.longDescription
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "</p>", with: "</p>\n")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "<li>", with: "<li>•\t")

        let descriptionAttributedString = eventDescription
            .style(tags: emStyle, iStyle, strongStyle, bStyle)
            .styleAll(allStyle)
            .attributedString

        descriptionTextView.attributedText = descriptionAttributedString
```

I usually would add line height to this text by:

```
descriptionTextView.attributedText = getAttributedStringWithLineHeight(text: eventDescription, font: .aicTextFont, lineHeight: 22)
```

But this doesn't seem to work - how can I add line height to the attributions that are already there?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems to have a `Style.paragraphStyle(someParam)` method in that lib. Line height should/could be done there.

Comment: Thank you @Larme, you are right. I didn't realize the method was available. So I created the style: `let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.0
            paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 22
            paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 22` then added it to the other styles: `let allStyle = Style.font(.aicTextFont).baselineOffset(22.0 - Float(UIFont.aicTitleFont.pointSize)).paragraphStyle(paragraphStyle)`

Comment: And so, does it work?